# Mysql: pivoting calculated data on itself

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

So I have this fairly large set of data that I'm reporting out on a predefined set of segments. I calculated the segments creating a series of sum case when statements. How do I present this data pivoted on itself? I'm trying to create a table that looks like this:

[image]

I wrote the code that generates the sums across the top based on how each color is defined. I hadn't had trouble presenting other data in column 1 because they were simple case when statements from a single field. Ultimately I want to present it as percents like the picture, but for now I'm trying to understand how to accomplish this. I can't do a select red, orange, etc etc because those fields are only calculated, not actual. How would I achieve something like this?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean adding in the code I wrote to generate the sums?

Comment: No. Normally, an RDBMS is used in conjunction with some kind of application code - PHP, for instance. It's often more efficient, and more scalable, to handle display issues there.

Comment: That sounds outside of my technical understanding. I’m  just hoping to do this in SQL since that’s what I’m mostly familiar with and how I’ve written the rest of the project to this point.

Comment: "how I’ve written the rest of the project2 - so it's just a bunch of queries?